# Python BeautifulSoup web scraping: Why section tag is not showing anything inside it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying the following code but not getting anything inside `section` tag

```
page = requests.get('https://www.iplt20.com/match/2018/20?tab=scorecard')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('section', {'class':'contentTab tab3 scorecardContent'})
```

I am getting the following result:
    `[<section class="contentTab tab3 scorecardContent" id="scorecardContent" style="display:none"></section>]`

Below is the section tag:
[image: Section Tag]

I checked and found that the content/text I want is in `innerText` but I am not able to fetch it

[image: innerText]

Please help, how can I get the details as shown in innerText?

Comment: You can get the result by querying [this API](https://cricketapi.platform.iplt20.com//fixtures/7913/scoring) directly.

Comment: Yes I can but I want to do it by myself. 
thanks @KeyurPotdar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`RequestsHTML`](https://html.python-requests.org/):

**Code:**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.iplt20.com/match/2018/20?tab=scorecard')
r.html.render()

tab3 = r.html.find('#scorecardContent', first=True)
print(tab3.text)
```

**Output:**

```
Sunrisers Hyderabad Innings (Run Rate: 8.90)
Batsmen
Runs
...
```